# Meteor: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'require'

Tags: javascript, meteor

I had problems previously trying to get the Meteor.require method to work and I thought it was fixed but apparently not.  Although I have since upgraded to Meteor 0.9.0.

Anyone have any idea how I can get the Meteor.require method to work?

Here's what I get on the terminal when passing params back to the server

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
I20140827-11:08:21.949(-7)? createImage
I20140827-11:08:21.953(-7)? 24890
I20140827-11:08:22.030(-7)? Exception while invoking method 'createImage' TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'require'
I20140827-11:08:22.032(-7)?     at Meteor.methods.createImage (app/server/server.js:7:21)
I20140827-11:08:22.033(-7)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1492)
I20140827-11:08:22.034(-7)?     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:643
I20140827-11:08:22.034(-7)?     at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56)
I20140827-11:08:22.034(-7)?     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:642
I20140827-11:08:22.034(-7)?     at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56)
I20140827-11:08:22.034(-7)?     at _.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:641)
I20140827-11:08:22.035(-7)?     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:541
```

This is my Meteor.method:

```
createImage: function(coords) {
   console.log('createImage')
   console.log(coords.area);
   var gd = Meteor.require('node-gd');
},
```

my packages.json file:

```
{
  "node-gd":"0.2.3"
}
```

node-gd is definitely there too:

```
me@ubuntu:~/leaderboard/packages/npm/npm/node_modules/node-gd$ ls
binding.gyp  build  coffee  cpp  js  package.json  README.md
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteorhacks just released (*I'm talking about 4 hours ago*) the updated npm package for `Meteor 0.9`, it's called `meteorhacks:npm` https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm

You should remove the previous package which I suppose is broken (something like `arunoda:npm` I guess) and give the new one a try.

Be aware that `Meteor.require` has been replaced by `Meteor.npmRequire` !

Comment: saimeunt, thanks again!  Just when I thought I had all the necessary updates!  I'll check this out and see if I can get it going!

Comment: looks like that's sorted - again!  Much appreciated!  I can finally get back to my project now :)  Thank you!!